# minimum graph coloring using backtracking

Tags: java, backtracking, pruning, graph-coloring

I am working an m_coloring problem wherein I have to determine the chromatic number m of an undirected graph using backtracking. The (java) solution I have thus far is increment m, try the m_Coloring method, and then repeat if a solution is not found. However, for the larger files, if m is over 6, the computation takes forever. I have been told that the algorithm we were given to use does not have pruning incorporated, so I am trying to figure out how to put it in and am having no luck after a week of searching.

```
vColor = new int[nodes+1];
vColor[1] = 1;
while(unsolved)
{
    m++;
    mColoring(1);
}

static void mColoring(int i)
{
    int color;
    if (promising(i))
    {
        if (i==nodes)
        {
            unsolved = false;
        }
        else
        {
            for(color = 1; color<=m; color++)
            {
                if(unsolved)
                {
                    vColor[i+1] = color;
                    mColoring(i+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

static public boolean promising (int i)
{
    int j=1;
    boolean promise = true;

    while(j<i && promise)
    {
        if(adjMatrix[i][j] && vColor[i] == vColor[j])
        {
            promise = false;
        }
        j++;
    }
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: [Here](https://secweb.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs361/web/website/Lectures/npprobs/pages/ar01s01s01.html) is some C++ code that implements your algorithm; it's close enough to Java that it ought to be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

A simple, efficient and well known exact algorithm uses [Brélaz](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=359101) minimum *degree of saturation* heuristic DSATUR (i.e. choose as new candidate vertex the one with less available colors, alias with more different colored neighbors) for branching inside a full [enumeration scheme](http://gcs1.googlecode.com/svn-history/r28/trunk/Recursos/BrownRandall.pdf).

The basic pruning strategy is implicit: every candidate vertex can only have at most as many colors as used in the preceding vertices + 1 (the new color, assigned if it is *saturated*). This means that the search can be pruned along any branch which backtracks on a vertex whose last assignment was a *new* color.

I am sorry I can give you no reference to a Java implementation of an exact DSATUR-based algorithm but I can give C, C++ refs if you are interested.